# How to add a new Rewrite rule in .htaccess file to target different files in the same folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AuthType Basic
AuthName "website"
AuthUserFile ""
require valid-user


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /article.php?slugId=$1 [L]
```

I want to add the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Adding this line at the end produces a server error since they both match the same. Both rules aim to change the URL of different files in the same folder.

What I want is to hit the following link

`website.com/y` where y could load category.php?category=category1

and also have

`website.com/x` where x could load article.php?slugId=some-slug

article.php and category.php would be two different files in the same folder.

How can I change the rules to make them work?

Comment: Its obvious its giving you an internal server error, because of your already existing rule. Could you please do let us know for which condition/type of URIs you want to rewrite by `article.php` AND for which URIs you want to write it to `category.php` then only we can fix it, without knowing on which condition which rule should be invoked its impossible to implement it IMHO.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I'm thinking that if I change the files to different folders and then change the rules to match the name of each folder respectively then it would work?

Comment: So you mean like lets say a url like `http://localhost:80/test1` is hit it should be served by `http://localhost:80/singh_file_backend.php` AND someone hits `http://localhost:80/test2` should be served by `http://localhost:80/singh_test2_file_backend.php`? Something like that?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 exactly, I've changed the question to make it clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples.

In following solution:

- Please change `firststring` with string which you want to look in URI while rewriting it to `article.php` in backend.
- Change `secondstring` with string which you want to look in URI while rewriting it to `category.php`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AuthType Basic
AuthName "website"
AuthUserFile ""
require valid-user

RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} firststring [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slugId=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} secondstring [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Alright, it's working now. This is what I wrote (if someone sees it later): RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /category1|category2|category3|category4/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ article.php?slugId=$1 [L]

Comment: @MiguelCardonaPolo, sure well done, you can edit my answer with adding this one and I will approve your edit then cheers. So that future users could get benifit by this one, I will approve your edit cheers and happy learning